# What is the advanced grammar topic used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, commas, sentence

I am having a difficulty trying to understand the structure of this sentence.

> Never does the discussion of constitutionalism in public law textbook, if it is discussed at all, exceed one page.

I do get the idea that the sentence tries to convey but it's very odd to read the sentence.

I highly appreciate if you could guide me on which English grammar topic I should look up.

Comment: You might want to Google *inversion never*. I think there is a typo btw., *textbookS*.

Comment: Your example has subject-auxiliary inversion. This occurs when certain elements such as negatives are placed in front position. "Never" is negative, so we have "never does the discussion ..." as opposed to the uninverted "the discussion of ... never exceeds one page".

Comment: Paraphrasing, 'The discussion of constitutionalism in public law textbooks (if it is discussed at all) is never allowed more than a single page.' But that would not falute high enough.

Comment: Define: "Advanced Grammar Topic" Are you unable to locate the subject and the verb?

Answer (score 2):

**Certain adverbs of frequency** are what explains the structure.

> The Cambridge Grammar says it like this:
> **Some adverbs** (e.g. hardly, little, never, only, scarcely and seldom) have a **negative meaning**. When we use these at the
> beginning of the clause, we invert the subject and verb:
>
> **Hardly** **had** we left the hotel when it started to pour with rain.
>
> Not: Hardly we had left the hotel
>
> **Little did** *we know* that we would never meet again.
>
> Only in spring **do we see** these lovely little flowers.
>
> We also invert the subject and verb after not + a prepositional phrase
> or not + a clause in front position:
>
> Not for a moment did I think I would be offered the job, so I was
> amazed when I got it.
>
> Not till I got home did I realise my wallet was missing.

[Cambridge Grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/negative-adverbs-hardly-seldom-etc)

The normal **declarative form** of the sentence is:

- "The discussion of constitutionalism in public law textbook, if it is discussed at all, never exceeds one page."

*If one of those adverbs begins a clause, then, the auxiliary is used with the adverb in front of it followed by the main verb*:

- "**Never does** the discussion of constitutionalism in public law textbook, if it is discussed at all, **exceed** one page."

In the simple present and simple past of transitive verbs, the auxiliary is put in. In other tenses, the auxiliary is already present.

- Little did he know that we were hiding in the room. [little is a special case ; in declarative form, it has to be said in a different way. "He had no idea we were hiding in the room".]
- Rarely did we go riding on Sunday. FOR: We rarely went riding on Sunday.

Here are some more examples:

From The Economist:

- **Seldom has** this *looked* so difficult. FOR: **This has seldom looked** more difficult. [Auxiliary already present]

From The New York Times:

- **Seldom has** the relationship **been more strained**. FOR: The relationship **has seldom been more strained**. [not a transitive, but seldom precedes the verb]
- **Rarely did they disagree**. FOR: **They rarely disagreed**.  [Auxiliary used]
  [ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/rarely+did) is a site where you can search newspaper texts.

The structure is usually found in formal writing. Though in Shakespeare's time it was spoken:

A rarer spirit **never

Did steer** humanity: but you, gods, will give us
Some faults to make us men.
Diomedes, Antony and Cleopatra
[IV, 14]

**Never** so much as in a thought unborn
**Did I offend** your Highness.
Rosalind, As You Like It
[I, 3]

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Bill J wrote:

> Your example has subject-auxiliary inversion. This occurs when certain elements such as negatives are placed in front position. "Never" is negative, so we have "never does the discussion ..." as opposed to the uninverted "the discussion of ... never exceeds one page".