# Are syntactic inversions mostly fixed?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, writing-style

I ask this because I want to know how the native in general would read a sentence like this:

Not rarely did they have dinner in that restaurant.

Does "not rarely" come across as weird? Pretentious? Creative? Or just incorrect altogether?
Someone had written this for an exam here in Brazil and got reproached on grounds that it was a literal misusage, since "not rarely" is common in written text here ("não raramente").
So I became wary of deviating from fixed expressions like "not only", "not until", "not a word". Thank you in advance.

Comment: The "inversion" in your example is the "fronting" of the adverbial element - which itself uses a *negated* form rather than a non-negated alternative such as *They **often** had dinner in that restaurant* (which "inverts" to *Often they had dinner there*). Your question seems to be about the (semantic) *negation*, not the (syntactic) *inversion*.

Comment: Hello, Peter. You have good instincts. In everyday conversation, 'Not rarely did they have dinner in that restaurant' comes across as highly unnatural, artificial, probably pretentious. However, similar inversions often work well in literature (though I'd prefer a less banal example): 'Not rarely did the winter snows block off all access to the mountain fortress.' // 'Not only ...' is far more common in everyday speech.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, hmm thank you for your take on it! I must make it clear that the whole clause was impromptu, the colloquial restaurant was first thing that came to mind, my mistake! I can't remember what se had written besides the adverbial. As to the exam, it is for graduates and aiming at diplomatic service, therefore academic in language and loaded with purism at times. So I was surprised with their correction.

Comment: Maybe the issue taken was more with the bilingual "bridge" for the expression than to its context, idk.

Comment: The sentence is grammatical but is strongly infelicitous due to the litotes and uncommon (unidiomatic) pairing of 'not rarely', plus the inversion. Look at the uninverted: "They had dinner not rarely in  that restaurant" - 'not rarely' is 'legal' but 'just not how you say it' in English.

Comment: _It was not unusual [for something to happen]_ is common enough, but _not rarely_ sounds very odd.

Comment: @Kate Bunting "Doctor, I keep thinking I'm Tom Jones."

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/598292/what-is-the-advanced-grammar-topic-used-in-this-sentence/598330#598330 Inversions and adverbs of frequency I think I answered this. The OP's question is grammatically correct but for that meaning one would tend to write: They often had dinner in that restaurant. However, it is not usually in the negative as often is usually used as a declarative.

Comment: I think you can compare it to something like *Not unknown was his love for cats*, where *not unknown* = *known*. His love for cats was known. It wasn't a secret. *Not rarely* = *often*. They had dinner in that restaurant often. It's legitimate and perfectly understandable, though probably found only in literary, not spoken, contexts.

Comment: It's largely just an awkward combination because it's, uh, so rarely used. On the other hand I recognise "It was not uncommon for [persons] to [action]" as a sentence. It is very much a "literary" form, as others have said already. Starting "It was not rare [for/that]..." is possible.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the preposition; we eat **at** restaurants, not **in** them.

Comment: @TinfoilHat true thing! p.s.  if the restaurant outdoor-furnishing policy is all-fern, no-table, would I be excused? lol

Answer (score 7):

My first thought was that OP's example seemed "odd" to me, though I couldn't immediately identify exactly *why*. Particularly after confirming my belief that [***rarely*** is far more common than ***infrequently***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=infrequently%2Crarely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)...

[image]

But [here's another chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20infrequently%2Cnot%20rarely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing how the situation reverses when those terms are *negated*...

[image]

I don't suppose there's any real "logic" to that reversal. But even though most native speakers wouldn't be *consciously* aware of it, it's obvious we all tend to fall in line with it in our own usages.

But I think it's worth me pointing out that although ***not rarely*** is relatively rare, writers / speakers who use the alternative ***not infrequently*** are *[often | frequently | not infrequently]* perceived as "pretentious". Use it at your own risk!

Comment: It definitely strikes me as odd-sounding: not literary, just odd. Part of the problem might be that while "not infrequently" obviously means "frequently" (and can be justified as litotes/understatement/politeness), it isn't so clear what "not rarely" means (it could even conceivably mean "never" in some contexts). It's a lot easier to understand negation with "not in/un-".

Comment: Starting a sentence out with "Rarely did" sounds a lot less strange than "Not rarely did" does here. I'm not quite sure why, but perhaps it's the litotes here that strains the ear.  "Little did I know" and such sound fine.

Answer (score 4):

The use of this form is literary. It's not used in conversation.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Mission_and_Catechesis/WMlDCgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22not+rarely+did%22&pg=PT116&printsec=frontcover)) Not rarely did he have to work clandestinely, hiding from place to place or under house arrest, and the Christians were forbidden to have contact with

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Law_of_Obligations/iFIT_NsmE7MC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22not+rarely+did%22&pg=PA842&printsec=frontcover))  Not rarely did it happen that someone made a performance in order to elicit some form of counterperformance on the part of the recipient

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is grammatical but is strongly infelicitous due to the [litotes](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/L/litotes.htm) and uncommon (unidiomatic) pairing of 'not rarely', plus the inversion.

Consider the uninverted version:

> "They had dinner not rarely in that restaurant."

'Not rarely' is 'legal' English but 'just not how you say it' in English. So yes, 'not rarely' is a little weird. Inversion in general is more characteristic of formal speaking and may come across as pretentious. A more idiomatic phrasing would be 'not seldom' which, while natural in the formal setting, does sound a little pretentious.

Comment: I think it should also be noted that the use of the negation when there's a non-negated form available adds to the "artificially complicated" feel of it. The sentence "They regularly had dinner in that restaurant" feels perfectly natural.

Comment: *They had dinner not seldom in that restaurant.* ? Not.

Comment: "Infelicitous" is nice, and I didn't know *litotes.* Reminds me of Adams' immortal "almost, but not quite, entirely unlike..."

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That's precisely what I said in my answer. My explanation falls into the more generic category of pragmatics, since every utterance has some pragmatic purpose, which is why a complicated negation that superficially has a simple logical equivalent almost always conveys something more than the negation.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are just saying that you "just don't use it" in everyday speech. But no concrete explanation is given, except for the vague remark on "litotes" by Mitch. I can offer a concrete explanation, which also explains [Edwin Ashworth's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1507299).

The explanation is simple: When you use such negations, you are conveying that the intended audience **typically believes** the non-negated form! So if you say "Not rarely did X do Y.", it conveys that your intended audience typically believes "X rarely did Y.", and also conveys your belief about their belief! But your cited statement about certain people having dinner in some restaurant then conveys something that makes no sense unless it is pretentious! This is because that statement appears to be a factual statement about a mundane activity, which *everyone* can observe for themselves, therefore *nobody* would normally believe "They rarely had dinner in that restaurant." if they in fact frequently had dinner there. So in any normal context, such a statement would appear pretentious since the speaker refused to use the ordinary phrasing "They frequently ..."!

In contrast, Edwin's example ("Not rarely did the winter snows block off all access to the mountain fortress.") is not pretentious, because it conveys that the intended audience believed incorrectly that the winter snow rarely blocked off all access to the mountain fortress, and is stated with the intention of fixing that misconception.

Comment: Interesting! I haven't known the real intent of using this figure of style till your explanation, thought the wording got the swap for swap's sake; I'll pay attention to the subtlety in meaning whenever the "not _adverb_" comes up!

Comment: What if there was a context, let's say, the couple was thought by their curious neighbors  to have their food delivered every night. Turns out it is the maid who dines at home and the headlines later says that maid revealed "couple not rarely went out for dinner at sushi-bar to have both dish and money laundered" (wt* situation)

Comment: @Peter: Doesn't what I said cover that too? The key is simply whether the writer or spekaer thinks the "intended audience" believes that "the couple" rarely went to that restaurant for dinner. If a news article writer thinks that the general reader would believe what those neighbours did, then it can fit. If not, then it doesn't fit.

Comment: Right, I had nosy neighbors in mind and I was probably not over the influence when writing that haha